# Connect google drive from paperspace gradient notebook - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python, authentication, jupyter-notebook, google-drive-api

I tried to use google drive with paperspace remote notebook (I mean a service for model training).
I created credentials in google cloude console and saved to client_secrets.json and placed it in a folder with executed notebook.
I use pydrive package to aunthenticate to google drive and run a code

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
```

And I get a page with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
[image: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]

Locally the authentication passes successfully.
Technical support of paperspace service was unable to reproduce the error.
Please give me the hint what could be the issue.
Thanks in advance.